# jquery mobile login form with php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have struggled with the code forever!! I keep getting the invalid password error and however many times I adjust where the hashing is or where to check the password I still get it even though i place the correct password for different users...I really need some help!
The table of 'users' in my db is
        id
        username
        password (sha1)
        fullnames
        mobile_no
        usertype
Here is the code I am currently trying to get to work!

```
       <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
          <h2 align="center"><strong>Sign In</strong></h2>
        </div>
       <div data-role="content">
          <form name="login" class="ui-corner-all" method="post" action="">
            <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name ="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name ="password" placeholder="Password"  required>
            <br>
            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
          <input name="login" type="submit"  id="login" formmethod="POST"          value ="login" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b">
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">
          <a href="Registration.html" data-ajax="false" data-role="button"     data-theme="b">Not a user? Sign Up</a></div>
      </fieldset> 
          </form>
          <?php   
      if (isset($_POST["login"]) && !empty($_POST["login"])) {

      $user = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
      $pass = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
      $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
      $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, hash("SHA1",($_POST['password'])));

      if ($user && $pass) {  // CHECK ALL FIELD HAS BEEN FILLED UP

      // QUERY FROM DATABASE
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'";
      $query =mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

      $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

      if($numrows !== 0)
      {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
      {
          $username = $row['username'];
          $password = $row['password'];

          }

          if($user==$username && $pass==$password)
          {
              echo "you are logged in";
              @$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
              }

              else {
                  echo "your password is incorrect";    
                  }
      }
                  else
                      die ("that user doesn't exist!");
                  }
                  else
                      die ("Please enter a username and password");
      }


          ?>
```

Comment: What is your question? And what is the error?

Comment: What if you print `$pass` value? Is it the same than the database value? Try to debug it step by step.

Comment: hey bub...my question is what am I doing wrong with the code? I keep getting password is incorrect...

Comment: what is the line of code I should put caCtus? and where...the echo of password is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. I am getting "you are logged in".
I just added session_start() and replaced variable in mysqli_real_escape_string()

```
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
            <h2 align="center">
                <strong>Sign In</strong>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form name="login" class="ui-corner-all" method="post" action="">
                <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username"
                    placeholder="Username" required> <br> <br> <label for="password"
                    class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label> <input
                    type="password" id="password" name="password"
                    placeholder="Password" required> <br>
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <input name="login" type="submit" id="login" formmethod="POST"
                            value="login" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a href="Registration.html" data-ajax="false" data-role="button"
                            data-theme="b">Not a user? Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <?php   
            $link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test");
            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            if (isset($_POST["login"]) && !empty($_POST["login"])) 
            {
                $user = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
                $pass = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
                $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $user);
                $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, hash("SHA1",($pass)));

                if ($user && $pass) {  // CHECK ALL FIELD HAS BEEN FILLED UP


                    // QUERY FROM DATABASE
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'";
                    $query =mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

                    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

                    if($numrows !== 0)
                    {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                        {
                            $username = $row['username'];
                            $password = $row['password'];
                        }

                        if($user==$username && $pass==$password)
                        {
                            session_start();
                            echo "you are logged in";
                            @$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "your password is incorrect";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        die ("that user doesn't exist!");
                }
                else
                    die ("Please enter a username and password");
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I got rid of the errors...but im still getting password incorrect with your adjustments, but the code is better though!

Comment: Please echo $sql and run it in the database editor or command prompt. Let me know what result you get when you run that.

Comment: this was what I got when I put it as the echoed error                           (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='eliza')

Comment: Ok lets forget about the database. Can you echo $numrows after line $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query); and echo $username and $password before line if($user==$username && $pass==$password). Please paste your result to me.

Comment: the echo for num rows was 1your password is incorrect                                              for the user and pass it was   jonny and 8103504b08e1015

Comment: when I run the eco for $user and $pass I got                                                 jonny and 8103504b08e101505a1eed7312a91a59b0e7e645 so the password is being truncated in the db therefore they can never match!! what can I change to make them match? the hashing or what?

Comment: You need to increase the character limit for the column in which password is saving. For that you need to access database. Do you have phpmyadmin? Is http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ working?

Comment: yes it is...which hashing needs the shortest character limit? or if im still using sha1 what limit should I put for the fields to match varchar 100?

Comment: You can add varchar 255.

Comment: I got this notice......Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project2\Login.php on line 82
you are logged in !                                                                                       ---but I think it will work! hopefully!!!        thank you so much...God bless!

Comment: I had that line at the top of the html doc...I removed that one! gracias!!  btw for the previous users to log in I have to update their passwords because they were truncated?

Comment: yes you have to reset the password for other users. please vote my answer up. :)